# fgetcsv not returning data from csv file

Tags: php, csv

```
// file opened with open before this
while ($dt = fgetcsv($dfp) !== FALSE) {
    $csvrows[] = $dt;
}
```

If I dump `$csvrows`, I get an array of bools each being `TRUE`. If I dump `$dt` within the loop, `$dt = TRUE`.

But this works:

```
// file opened with open before this
while ($dt = fgetcsv($dfp) !== FALSE) {
    $csvrows[] = fgetcsv($dfp);
}
```

I get the data from my CSV file nicely populated into `$csvrows` (but I am missing rows of data, because `fgetcsv($dfp)` is also called in the evaluation statement of the loop.

How come, and how do I solve to get all the data in my CSV file?

The PHP documentation says that what `fgetcsv` returns is an array of data, not a bool.

Comment: Use [PHPOffice PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) package to read csv file using PHP.

Comment: This doesn't really deal with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) issue. You can add some parentheses to specify the correct grouping.

```
while (($dt = fgetcsv($dfp)) !== FALSE) {
```

Changing the order in the expression should also work.

```
while (false !== $dt = fgetcsv($dfp)) {
```

As it's currently written, you're assigning the result of `fgetcsv($dfp) !== FALSE` to `$dt`, because comparison has a higher precedence than assignment.